# How to add grabMultiple method into WebGuy

Tags: codeception

This method is listed on method list here: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabMultiple but I'm getting error "Call to undefined method WebGuy::grabMultiple" so I tried to update and build but without success.

Here is code:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
./codecept.sh build
```

This is my acceptance.yaml:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled: 
      - MailCatcher
      - Selenium2
      - WebHelper
    config:
      Selenium2:
         url: 'http://localhost'
         host: selenium.localhost
         browser: firefox
         capabilities:
             unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
      MailCatcher:
         url: 'http://localhost'
         port: '1080'
```

Is anything else I need to do to get this new method?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are upgrading from Codeception 1.6 or older -
Selenium2 module was renamed to WebDriver in 1.7.

Change Selenium2 to WebDriver in your configuration files.

Comment: Method is still not here. It looks I should completely remove old vendor folder and upgrade to new codeception

Comment: Choose one method of installation - phar or composer.

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: If you use both in the same project, you have a potential source of conflicts. I recommend using composer if your project uses Symfony or Guzzle or some other dependency of Codeception or if you run it on PHP 5.4.